# Swift equivalent of id<MyProtocol>?

Tags: objective-c, swift, delegates, protocols

The question is in the title. In Objective-C, if I want to have a property (like a delegate) that **HAS** to adhere to a certain protocol it can be defined like so:

```
@property (weak) id<MyDelegate> delegate;
```

How can I do this in Swift?

Comment: Here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A protocol is a type, so you can use it as a declared variable type. To use `weak`, you must wrap the type as an Optional. So you would say:

```
weak var delegate : MyDelegate?
```

But in order for this to work, MyDelegate must be an `@objc` or `class` protocol, in order to guarantee that the adopter is a class (not a struct or enum, as they cannot be `weak`).

Comment: And see my book for more about this: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_memory_management_of_protocol_typed_references

Answer (score 1):

I think the exact oposite is:

```
weak var delegate: protocol<MyDelegate>?
```

I prefer this old, objc, style over the swift syntax because in swift first is the base class and then all the adopted protocols. This may be confusing in case your protocol does not have "Delegate" suffix as you won't know whether DataAdoption(for example) is super class or a protocol.

Comment: This was deprecated in Swift 4 :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use the protocol like a type, so:

```
weak var delegate:MyDelegate?
```

Comment: Weak variables must always be of optional type.

Answer (score 0):

It is also good to know the equivalent for the Objective-C `id<MyProtocolName>` in the method declaration in Swift is `protocol<MyProtocolName>`. For Example:

```
// Objective-C
-void myMethodWithSome:(id <MyProtocolName>)param {
   // ...
}

// Swift
func myMethodWithSome(param: protocol<MyProtocolName>) {
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for method declarations

Objective-C

```
-void myMethodWithSome:(id <MyProtocolName>)param {
   // ...
}
```

Swift

```
func myMethodWithSome(param: MyProtocolName) {
   //...
}
```